# Concatenate Fields into One Field in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have seen some posts on this, but only for ArcMap.  I am looking to take a range of values from two fields and concatenate them into one field to make a unique value.  For example:

```
XMAX     YMAX       GRIDID
332500   5366000    33255366
333000   5366000    33305366
```

In ArcMap you can do something like `(Mid([XMAX]),1,4)+(Mid([YMAX]),1,4)`.

I know this can be done in a PostGIS database, but for the moment it needs to be done on a shapefile and I am looking to use QGIS.

Thanks

Comment: Are "XMAX" and "YMAX" actually string fields or are they really numeric?

Comment: They are numbers.  But I converted the number values to string in new columns and the calculation Jef supplied still didn't work.

Comment: Why not just combine them numerically then? The simplest example assumes all values of "XMAX" are six-digit multiples of 100 and all values of "YMAX" are seven-digit multiples of 1000: "XMAX"*100+"YMAX"/1000 does the trick. More generally you may need to do some rounding of the values before carrying out this calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In QGIS it's almost the same: `substr("XMAX",1,4)||substr("YMAX",1,4)` in the field calculator.

Comment: Thank you Jef.  I have tried this, but it does not return anything.  The field remains NULL.

Comment: Hm, works for me in 1.8.  If you are using an earlier version try: `substr(tostring("XMAX"),1,4)||substr(tostring("YMAX"),1,4)`

Comment: I was am using 1.7.4.  Is your output new field a String?  My input fields are Whole Numbers.

Comment: no, `xmax`, `ymax` and `gridid` are whole numbers - but the conversions should happen transparently. But I think the expression engine was completely redone in 1.8, so ymmv with 1.7.   `toint(...)` should still help there.

Comment: Yeah the 1.8 and 1.7 expression engines are different

Comment: I found this answer on Google, but don't know the basics, ie. where to actually enter this concatenation instruction... What's the 'field calculator'?